# Routing error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have

```
def update_project_dates
  p "It is end date....."
  @user=User.find(params[:user])
  @projects=Project.find_all_by_user_id(@user)
end
```

In the view page (only some part of the code is copied and pasted)

```
eventDrop: function() 
{ 
  $.ajax({
    url:'/update_project_dates/',
    success:function(data)
    {
    alert("Hello");
    }
  })
},
```

In my routes.rb I have mentioned

```
match '/update_project_dates' => 'users#update_project_dates', :method=> :get
get 'update_project_dates'
```

But When the ajax request goes, I get the routing error as

> ## Routing Error
>
> ```
> uninitialized constant UsersController
> ```

Where am I doing wrong here...Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Your matching route

```
match '/update_project_dates' => 'users#update_project_dates'
```

dispatches the request to the `users` controller’s `update_project_dates` action.

The error message however says that there is no `UsersController`. Make sure you are referring to the correct controller and that you haven't misspelled it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should have this in your routes...

```
map.resources :users
```

which makes rails assume the controller is named UsersController (it's the default convention for this)

if You just want to make it singular.

```
map.resources :users, :controller => 'user'
```

or you just consider following Rails convention and renaming your controller to UsersController.

[Multiple child models in dynamic form](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=28447)